# php script not run in 4.2(jelly bean) emulator

Tags: android

I had made php script and i want to execute this php script from android.
to execute php script i write following code:

```
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse httpResponse;
        try
        {
            //execute php script for creating group
        HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet("http://ip address/CreateGroup.php?gname=temp&desc=grouptesting);

        try {
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This code is work in 2.3.3(GINGERBREAD_MR1) emulator.
but in 4.2(jelly bean) emulator not work.
Is there any version gap?? please give me reason of above problem....

Comment: seems to me like you're calling network on main thread. please add your logcat

Comment: Are you trying to load the script from assets folder or really using http..

Comment: I am using linux fedora 17 os. I put php script in /var/www/html/ folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be willing to bet you're getting a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.  In Honeycomb, this exception was introduced to make sure you do these kind of long running tasks on a background thread.  Without any more information, I'd assume this to be the case if it works pre-Honeycomb and doesn't work post-Honeycomb.

Comment: thanks Rich  for your answer,the problem is NetworkOnMainThreadException , i solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. You have to use [SSLSocketFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html)

HttpClient httpclient = getNewHttpClient();

```
public HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
        try {
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore
                    .getDefaultType());
            trustStore.load(null, null);

            SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
            sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

            SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
            registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory
                    .getSocketFactory(), 80));
            registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));



            ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(
                    params, registry);

            return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new DefaultHttpClient();
        }
    }
```

**MySSLSocketFactory.java**

```
public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
    super(truststore);

    TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
    };

    sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
    return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
}
```

}